# How to merge Mutiny MATE into the top Title Bar (Like Unity 7 used to save screen space)

Tags: panel, mate, ubuntu-mate, titlebar, mutiny

I have a question about Ubuntu MATE using the Mutiny Appearance configuration.

When I maximize my terminal or LibreOffice, it still leaves the title bar.

[image: screenshot with launcher and top panel and application window top bar]

not merged into the TOP PANEL. How can I merge it? In the old Unity 7 Ubuntu 17.04, it used to merge into the top bar.

Can this be done with MATE?

Do you guys have any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open MATE Tweak and check "*Undecorate maximised windows*" under *Windows*.

[image]

**Warning:** Title bar of a maximised window will vanish completely. You won't see window control buttons (close, minimise, maximise) for maximised windows. You'll have to use keyboard shortcuts.
Most probably Ubuntu MATE 18.04 will [have the window control buttons](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-will-bring-undecorated-maximized-windows-for-mutiny-layout-518583.shtml).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, do you know if there is a way to add the close maximize buttons into the full screen? If not no problem, thank you so much for your help.... Thank you all at the AskUbuntu Community, regards & cheers!

Comment: @WubiUbuntu1980 Unfortunately it's probably not ready yet, but it should arrive soon! "*We're working on window control buttons for the "Global Menu". Not sure if it will be ready for 17.10 but it is in progress. And yes, it will work in conjunction with undecorated maximised windows.*" said Martin Wimpress (the person behind Ubuntu MATE) in reply to a comment [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-artful-alpha2/).

Comment: Ohhh!!! Great!! Hopefully the next version of MATE will be fixed to include this. Thank you so much for sharing this!

Comment: @WubiUbuntu980Unity7Refugee This might interest you: http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-will-bring-undecorated-maximized-windows-for-mutiny-layout-518583.shtml

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Wow I am so happy the developers did this!!! Do you know if there is a way to make the Mutiny Environment the default by editing the iso file?